# How to replace tab with &nbsp; in PHP?

Tags: php, html, str-replace, nl2br

In my database I have the following text:

```
for x in values:
   print x
```

I want to print this code on my HTML page. It is printed by PHP to the HTML file as it is. But when HTML is displayed by a browser I, of course, do not see text in this form. I see the following:

```
for x in values: print x
```

I partially solved the problem by `nl2br`, I also use `str_replace(' ','&nbsp',$str)`. As a result I got:

```
for x in values:
print x
```

But I still need to shift `print x` to the right. I thought that I can solve the problem by `str_replace('\t','&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$str)`. But I found out that `str_replace` does not recognize the space before the print as '\t'. This space is also not recognized as just a space. In other words, I do not get any `&nbsp;` before the `print`.

Why? And how can the problem be solved?

Comment: Why not putting the text to be displayed inside a <pre> tag?

Comment: http://php.net/types.string <- a text that every PHP developer should learn by heart

Answer (score 12):

Quote the text in double quotes, like this

```
str_replace("\t", '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $str);
```

PHP will interpret special characters in double quoted strings, while in single quoted strings, it will just leave the string, with the only exception of `\'`.

---

*Old and deprecated answer:*

Copy the tab character ("   ") from notepad, your databasestring or this post, and add this code:

```
str_replace('   ','&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$str);
```

(this is not four spaces, it is the tab character you copied from notepad)

Answer (score 10):

You need to place `\t` in double quotes for it to be interpreted as a tab character. Single quoted strings aren't interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

always use double quotes when using \t \n etc

Answer (score 3):

It can be tricky because tabs don't actually have a fixed size and you'd have to calculate tab stops. It can be simpler if you print blank space as-is and instruct the browser to display it. You can use `<pre>` tags:

```
<pre>for x in values:
   print x</pre>
```

... or set the `white-space` CSS property:

```
div.code{
    white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

*(As noted by others, `'\t'` is different from `"\t"` in PHP.)*